# Redirect Windows boot screen

Tags: windows, redirection

I know you can somehow print Windows booting sequence messages, you know, such as loading ntoskrnl.exe, hal.dll and so when Windows is booting withoug GUI into file, but I can´t find how. Please, help. Thank.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> before Windows starts and select `Enable Boot Logging`.

Answer (score 2):

Open run and type: 'msconfig' 
In the boot tab there is a 'No Gui Boot' and a 'Boot Log' option. Ensure that both are checked. Hit apply then reboot. 
If that doesn't work, or for further information refer to: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325376
- ntw1103